# How do I edit robots.txt on a site hosted with Google Sites?

Tags: robots.txt, google-sites

I need to make changes to someone's *robots.txt* file, but their site is managed by Google Sites (so no FTPing).

I have full access to the site via the browser (Site Actions / Manage Site, etc.) but how do I get to the *robots.txt* file to update it?

Comment: You can't. There is no robots.txt file other than the one for the main site.

Comment: Then what's all this about?
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en

If you open the Tester and click Submit, it even gives you directions: "Upload the updated robots.txt to your domain's root..."

Comment: @kwik,  that assumes you have access to that on your web server. In your case, you don't. Different part of Google. You would probably have more luck asking about what you need to accommodate lush because there might be another way.

Answer (score 7):

The robots.txt file is located at https://sites.google.com/robots.txt.

You don't have access to edit that file, it is automatically generated by Google.

The article you are referring to is generalized for how most website owners or admins can make changes.

Answer (score -3):

for Sites Google, you can test or edit robots.txt
here:
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool?utm_source=support.google.com/webmasters/&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign

Comment: You are linking to the robots texting tool from Google Search Console.  That tool is not part of Google Sites, it is a general tool that can be used by any website to see what impact changing the robots.txt file has on Googlebots ability to crawl the site.  Any changes you make within that tool not saved back to your site.   That tool is only a preview tool, it can't make changes to the robots.txt file for your site.